# How not to overwrite a file

Tags: c#

I save text into .txt-file. Afterwards I want to add some new text to the file. If I run the code to write new text,  it overwrites the old content. How can I prevent this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class Level02WON : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        string line = "Level02 = true";
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
           new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\Cubator\Level Data\Level02DATA.txt");
        file.WriteLine(line);
        file.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: `FileMode.Append`

Comment: Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Adds: Or even simpler, `AppendAllText` that opens the file for append or creates it if it didn't exist, writes the new content, and closes the file, all in a single function call.

Comment: Cool !!! Thanks @BenVoigt

Comment: You should be `using (System.IO.StreamWriter ....) {}` as its disposable.

Answer (score 4):

You should use another constructor of [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx), that allows appending, like this:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
```